# jQuery replacing spans in node+jade combo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, pug

Perhaps this is expected, but I found it odd since I am now starting with jQuery.

So, I am writing an application using node and jade. In the index.jade I have a statement of the form

```
  p Welcome subscriber 
      span(id="subscriber") someID
```

Now once the connection is established between the client and the server, the server sends a welcome JSON message with some data. One of them is the id of the client which I want to replace above. Once the client receives the welcome JSON message it initializes the appropriate structures and then I make a call to a function loadStats:

```
function loadStats() {
  var myText = "" + myData.id + ".";
  $('#subscriber').text(myText);
  $('#subscriber').html(myText);
};
```

In the screen I can see that the text "someID" is replaced by the ID of the client. However, when I actually inspect the html code of the page that I am looking at I see a statement of the form:

```
<p>Welcome subscriber <span id="subscriber">someID</span></p>
```

In other words in the actual HTML code the text "someID" has not been replaced. Is this something expected? How was the replacement done? Moreover, it appears that working with either of the statements

```
  $('#subscriber').text(myText);
  $('#subscriber').html(myText);
```

gives the replication on the screen but not on the actual html content of what is presented on screen. Is this the correct behavior? From what I understood (and expect) the .text() replaces the visual data of the element with the specific id and the .html() replaces the content. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance. jQuery rookie here.

Comment: I think it might be that the debugger you're using hasn't updated to reflect the changed html/text content. Maybe try seeing what `$('#subscriber').text()` outputs?

Comment: @theabraham You were right. Please add it as an answer and I will accept. I also realized my mistake on the understanding between text() and html(), so, no need to refer to that. As a minor comment, I am running the scripts on the browser only after using browserify because I am sharing many of those with the server and require() commands. I am not sure if this is the expected behavior otherwise. Honestly, my experience in jQuery is a few hours. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Two rules for expressions in pug:

1. In attributes you use quotes to output literal text and you leave the quotes out when you want to use a variable, and
2. For the content of a tag you use an equals sign when you want pug to evaluate an expression, or don't put anything if you want literal text

So with those rules in mind, looking at your code you will output the attribute "subscriber" as a literal and "someId" as a literal.

```
span(id="subscriber") someID
```

Results in:

```
<span id="subscriber">someId</span>
```

You wanted both to be dynamic so remove the quotes in the attribute and put an equals sign after the element:

```
span(id= subscriber)= someID
```

This will dynamically replace both with variables.